# LCD SPLC780D Initialization sequence fails

Tags: pic, lcd, character-lcd

Microcontroller model : PIC32MX340F512H
LCD controller : SPLC780D
LCD module : MC42005A6W-FPTLW3-V2 (20*4)

I have been struggling for two weeks to get a SPL780D based LCD module to work. I checked the wiring and the code with the timers many times, based on the datasheet and a lot of examples. Alone, and with other people.

I use this function to send instructions to the LCD module:

```
void send(int rs, int rw, unsigned char db)
{
    RS = rs;
    RW = rw;
    wait(1000);//26ms
    E = 1;
    wait_k(1000);
    DB0 = (db & (1 << 0)) ? 1:0;
    DB1 = (db & (1 << 1)) ? 1:0;
    DB2 = (db & (1 << 2)) ? 1:0;
    DB3 = (db & (1 << 3)) ? 1:0;
    DB4 = (db & (1 << 4)) ? 1:0;
    DB5 = (db & (1 << 5)) ? 1:0;
    DB6 = (db & (1 << 6)) ? 1:0;
    DB7 = (db & (1 << 7)) ? 1:0;
    wait_k(1000);
    E = 0;
}
```

I tried many other delays, and I follow the sequence below:

[image: LCD initialisation flowchart]

Can someone please help me? Launching the sequence makes the screen blink once, and then I only have two lines of black boxes.

I am starting to think it is broken.

Adding the complete code below:

```
#define DB0 LATDbits.LATD4
#define DB1 LATDbits.LATD5
#define DB2 LATDbits.LATD6
#define DB3 LATDbits.LATD7  
#define DB4 LATDbits.LATD8
#define DB5 LATDbits.LATD9
#define DB6 LATDbits.LATD10
#define DB7 LATDbits.LATD11

#define E   LATDbits.LATD3
#define RS  LATDbits.LATD0
#define RW  LATDbits.LATD1

void wait_k(int k)
{
    while (k)
    { k -= 1; }
}

void    init(void)
{
    LATDbits.LATD0 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD1 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD3 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD4 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD5 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD6 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD7 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD8 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD9 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD10 = 0;
    LATDbits.LATD11 = 0;

    TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD1 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD3 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD4 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD5 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD6 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD7 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD8 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD9 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD10 = 0;
    TRISDbits.TRISD11 = 0;

}

int main ()
{
    init();
    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00110000);

    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00110000);


    wait_k(100);
    send(0, 0, 0b00110000);


    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00110000);


    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00001000);

    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00000001);

    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00000111);

    //----End Of INIT

    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00111000);//Function Set

    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00001110);// Display on

    wait_k(1000);
    send(0, 0, 0b00000110);//Entry mode set

    wait_k(1000);
    send(1, 0, 0b01010111);//Write 'W'

    while(42);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you assigning `RS`, `RW` and `E`? ... your code does not do seem to do anything with them .... please post the complete code

Comment: Thank you for answering, I added the complete in the post. RS/E/RW are macros I set to make reading easier.

Comment: mcu model ? also keep it simple, all LATDbits and TRISDbits could be replaced by "LATD = 0; TRISD = 0;"

Comment: the controller I use is : pic32mx340f512h. You are right for the LATDbits part, I chose to do it like that because it was easier that way for me to check and change the wiring

Comment: @MehdiSabwat - I don't have a PIC32MX to run any of your code. However, just to eliminate some possibilities: (a) Have you used an oscilloscope to confirm that the signal waveforms are valid, and an oscilloscope or logic analyser to confirm the actual timings are correct according to the controller datasheet? If so, what were the results? (b) Have you tried a completely different LCD module (e.g. a common 16x2 etc.)? If so, what were the results? (c) Have you done any other relevant troubleshooting (if so, what was it?) or have you focussed only on the code & wiring of your existing setup?

Comment: Thank you for answering @SamGibson. (a) I did use an oscilloscope to check the the delays and multimeter to check for voltage in the pins. I am planning on checking with the logic analyser in a few hours. b) we did not test our code in any other lcd, might be a good thing to do you are right c) we tested different delays, and different methods we discovered in forums.

Comment: @MehdiSabwat - Thanks. (a) Using a multimeter to check logic voltages isn't enough. Since you have a 'scope, use *that* to check for valid & stable logic low/high voltages and sensible rise/fall times on *all* signals. (b) Yes, try a different LCD module on that MCU and/or try that LCD module on a different/simple MCU e.g. Arduino. (c) Thanks, so I suggest you expand your analysis outside just that code and *that* LCD module, as suggested in my point (b). (d) No hardware schematic, photos & test results provided. Although you checked the wiring, there are other possible faults. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was a wiring problem. Using a Logical Analyser (saleae 16 logic)to profile the Signals was EXTREMELY helpful.
Also, Really important to clear the bits before you send them back